# How to resume video playback after the surface was destroyed?

Tags: java, android, media-player, rtsp

I'm working with the media player on a streaming application (RTSP):

Video and sound are played great but when an incoming call pauses the `Activity`, the Surface is destroyed (I know this because of traces in `SurfaceHolder.Callback`).

Once the call finishes, the activity is resumed and a new `Surface` is created. I've tried to  assign it to the player via `setDisplay(SurfaceHolder sh)` method but so far, only the sound of the video can be heard.

The work around to resume a video stream is:

- Restart the `MediaPlayer` object.
- Wait for the buffer to fill.
- Perform a seek via the mediaPlayer.
- Wait for the buffer to fill.

This is annoying as the player should be able to be paused when a call is received, bind the new surface when the call completed and the `Activity` resume and play the video with no buffering at all.

Comment: hey am in the same situation have you been able to work around it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding "onStop" or even "onDestroy" and somehow make the player persitent?
Edith just showed me the timestamp of this question. Is it of any interest still?

Comment: This was an issue only on a certain model of Android 1.6. I don't think this is relevant anymore.